# Do we have for any bounded projection $P$, $\left\Vert Px\right\Vert =\left\Vert P\right\Vert \left\Vert x\right\Vert $ for some non-zero $x\in H$?

Tags: operator-theory, hilbert-spaces, projection

Les $H$ be a Hilbert space and $P\in B\left( H\right) $ a bounded
projection. I made some drawing to try to find such an $x$, and I found that
$x~$is any non zero vector in the image of $P^{\ast }\left( 1-P\right) $ in
case $P$ is not orthogonal, or in the image of $P$ in case $P$ is orthogonal.
But I found very hard to formalize a proof, I began by computing :

$\left\langle Px,Px\right\rangle =\left\langle x,x\right\rangle
+\left\langle \left( I-P\right) x,\left( I-P\right) x\right\rangle $ since $%
\left( I-P\right) x\in Ker \left( P\right) =Im\left( P^{\ast
}\right) ^{\bot },$ and that's all.

Is there any such $x$ and any explicit formula giving it ?

Thank you !

Comment: Isn't the restriction of $P$ to its range equal to the identity?

Comment: @uniquesolution I think OP is only assuming that $P^{2}=P$ and $P$ bounded. The solution is obvious if $\|P\|=1$ but that is not given.

Comment: Yes, $P=P^{2}$ since it is a projection

Comment: yes, the restriction of $P$ to its range is the identity

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps a bit surprisingly, not every bounded projection in a Hilbert space attains its norm. The following example is taken from [this paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/2101.03585.pdf). (The symbol $\mathcal{NA}$ stands for Norm-Attaining.)
That paper also contains a necessary and sufficient condition for a projection in Hilbert space to be norm-attaining.

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much, it is a very big surprise lol